# How to delegate all building and all executing to maven

Tags: intellij-idea

Lately (even after cache cleanup/reinstalls) I have issues with idea, where builds are failing, run configuration is failing. The problem is, that it is idea thing, maven builds just fine, run from cli runs just fine.

In idea I already checked "delegate build/run configurations to maven", and run configuration does not have any action to be done before build. Yet for some reason when I click run, it tries to download some libraries and then it fails. Second later `java -jar` from cli using previously outside of intellij build jar WORKS.

How to turn all these clever (and for me dysfunctional) stuff? I just want idea to run java -jar and that's it to minimize number of places, where it can fail. I know about possibility starting code externally from java and just connect with debugger, but I'd like to avoid it as it is not that convenient, and if I have ultimate edition, I'd like to be able to start debugging session from ide.

EDIT:
maven project is freshly updated, jdk is the same as one used maven. Yet for some reason project run produces:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
```

second later, java -jar using fat jar works.

Comment: Is it possible to properly run your application using Maven goal?

Comment: I can build app from idea using maven. I can use `java -jar <built-fat-jar>` to run it externally. I'm not aware if there is some universal way how to do `java -jar ...` using maven, so I did not try that neither from cli nor from IDEA. Please advise. But something fishy is going on. I have no idea why if my run configuration does not have make/build/anything to do before launch, why idea is trying to download something. "Just take what is already present, don't anything you weren't ask for, and launch that app"

Comment: If you have "delegate build/run configurations to maven" then probably it's maven downloading some staff. Is it possible to share some project example for investigation?

Comment: well, "maven" seems to be downloading it ONLY when run from idea, so I kinda doubt it's maven. Sadly no, it's internal project. But it is happening to me around the clock: new project using java 11. maven builds. Reimports, reimport, reimport, restart idea. Try to run debug configuration fails with "UnAbLe To CoMpIle tO jAva 5.". Invalidate caches, restart idea. Now it works. So I'd really like to somehow fix idea by disabling some faulty parts, as it happened to me (and not only me) that I'm debugging idea fails, while our code is fine (mostly after clearing caches)

Comment: ACTUALLY, when running run configuration without ANY build configured in it, AND having set "delegate build/run configuration to maven" idea will invoke SOMETHING using maven driving run configuration execution to failure. Turning that delegation to mave to false makes run configuration working. So users recommendation if idea misbehaves: do not delegate, do not have anywhere any make/build options, and build using maven outside of idea. If anything breaks (regularly) reimport maven, drop caches and restart.

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to investigate such case without sample project. Is it possible to share any example?

Comment: I cannot share the any of my failing projects, I don't own the sources. When it happens on my own project, I will ping here, no problem. But the situation is very common and frequent. 2y old idea installations, fresh ones, old&new projects. All my colleges experiences that. For example, when there is dependency missing in maven pane, you might reimport all day long, and nothing will happen until you close&reopen project.

Comment: Are there any error/warning messages in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") when the issue occurs?

Comment: I went over logs, and disabled all failing plugins (stock grable and multirun) I will monitor logs and if I find something noteworthy I'll update.